# Como abrir o instagram usando iframe?

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando abrir o meu perfil do instagram usando um iframe, para por meu insta no meu site, mas ate agora não consegui, parasse que o instagram tem um tipo de bloqueio.

```
 <iframe id="frame" src="https://www.instagram.com/turingcursosdeti/" frameborder="0" width="320" height="568"></iframe>
```

Eu sei que tem alguns sites que abrem o perfil do instagram, e que eu podia usá-los, como por exemplo.

```
<iframe id="frame" src="https://web.stagram.com/leomessi" frameborder="0" width="320" height="568"></iframe>
```

O problema e que agrande maioria destes sites tem anúncios, e os que não tem anúncios sempre tem algum tipo de menu, que não e tão responsivo, ou e muito diferente do instagram, o que acaba deixando as coisas meio estranhas.

A alguma forma de contornar isso e abrir o instragram, diretamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não consegue abrir o Instagram dessa forma pois este não permite que websites externos coloquem o website deles num frame. A única forma que tem de por o instagram num frame é sendo um Post, como por exemplo https://www.instagram.com/p/BxFc58nFwpN/ e tem que ter sempre o sufixo */embed* como por exemplo está aqui:

```
<iframe id="frame" width="320" height="568" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/BxFc58nFwpN/embed" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: O link que você postou está quebrado

Comment: Já corrigi, obrigado